# Actual velocity of an non-accelerating object in Newtonian physics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, velocity, inertial-frames, observers, relative-motion

How was the velocity of an non-accelerating object (i.e moving at a constant velocity) in empty space, determined in Newtonian physics? Did Newton also considered it to be at rest, if not how is its speed determined?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. How do you know that an object is moving at constant velocity if you do not know how to measure its velocity? If your question is related to the choice of the reference frame, you should try to recast it.

Comment: Newton was familiar with [Galilean relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_invariance).

Answer (score 4):

From the Principia, Newton writes the first law as:
*Lex I: Corpus omne perseverare in statu suo quiescendi vel movendi uniformiter in directum, nisi quatenus illud a viribus impressis cogitur statum suum mutare.*

or, "Law I: Every body perseveres in a state of being at rest or of moving uniformly straight forward except insofar as it is compelled to change its state by forces impressed."

The two cases of being at rest, or at constant velocity just depend on the inertial frame of reference used by the observer. Different observers can, and will, have different values for an object's velocity, but will agree on its acceleration.